# clang-format: How do I dump a language-specific default config?

Tags: clang-format

To get a default config, I just have to do `clang-format -dump-config`. However, the default configuration is always for `Cpp`. Using the `-style` or `-assume-filename` flag does not seem to change the `Language:` option in the default config dump.

Is there any way I can get a default config for any other language(JavaScript, for instance)?
Or at least get the config which `clang-format` follows when I use it on a `.js` script without any `.clang-format` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the clang-format binary a file while dumping the configuration, it will base the dumped configuration on the file type that was given. For example, if you wish to dump a configuration and have the Language set to JavaScript, pass it a .js file such as:

```
clang-format --style=LLVM --dump-config test.js
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I finally generated a Java .clang-format file.  Thank you!